# How to reopen an FTP project in VSCode with ftp-simple without the need to download every file info again

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using the ftp-simple extension in VSCode to auto upload changes on save. This works fine, but there is 1 problem.

The FTP server I'm saving to is quite large so the first time I open a connection to it, it will "Remote info download" all the files on the server, this takes a very long time.

But when I close the connection and I reopen it let's say a day later, it has to re download the file info of every file again. Is there a way to "remember" all of that?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the workplace, and in my experince it enhance load time quite a bit.